# Creating buffer from click on map on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I'm searching a way to creating a buffer of a specified radius starting from a click on the map.

Answer (score 2):

Add the Editor toolbar and start an edit session.

Highlight a feature on the map and click on the Editor menu.

Click on Buffer and set the buffer distance.

[image]

---

If you need something else, the easiest way would probably be to create a [Python addin](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000). It's kind of hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do from your question.